# Merging hotfix branch to develop re-introduces old changes

Tags: git, git-flow

We have been trying git flow in our team. We create release branch base off of `develop` branch. Then we merge release branch to `develop` and `master` after release. We have made several releases so far without hotfix.

Now, we just had an incident that needed a hotfix (first hotfix). so we created hotfix branch based off of `master`. We merged hotfix branch to master, it was all good. Then we tried to merge hotfix branch to `develop`, and diff shows old changes being reintroduced to `develop`. For example, there are files that should have been deleted but were re-added into develop after merge. Prior to merging, both staging and master are the same (no diff whatsoever).

Any idea what is causing this? I wanted to show sample history/graph but our history is very cluttered due to merges.

Comment: Update: it turns out there are differences between develop and master when I do `git diff develop master`. Also when I compare branches master -> develop in Gitlab, it shows differences, but when comparing develop -> master, no diff. Very odd.

Comment: Update: the missing link turned out to be that we were not merging master to develop  such that merge base is far away from the current head. Merging master to develop every time master is updated and making sure it is merged to develop before creating release branch removed the conflicts described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea what is causing this?

The choice of merge base commit, of course.  This choice is not *yours:* Git makes it automatically, based on the commit graph.  That's why *this* step:

> so we created hotfix branch based off of `master`

was probably the founding error (or "root cause", if you prefer).

You can see which commits Git considers to be the merge base(s) for `develop` and `master` using:

```
git merge-base --all develop master
```

This will print out one or more commit hash IDs.<sup>1</sup>  If it prints just *one* hash ID—which is the usual case—then that one hash ID is the hash ID of the merge base commit.  If it prints two or more, Git will *construct* a merge base (for `git-merge-recursive` anyway) by merging the listed commits; these situations are tricky.

Remember that `git merge` is all about *combining changes*, yet Git does not *store* changes at all.  Git stores *snapshots:* each commit holds a full snapshot of every file, as a sort of frozen-in-time archive, saying that this is how the project is at this (snapshot) time.  The only way to turn snapshots into changes is to take at least *two* snapshots and compare them, as if playing a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).

Spotting the differences between the two branch tips (`master` and `develop`) is not useful, because applying those differences to one of the branch tips would just produce the other snapshot.  (In which case, why are we even bothering with branches?)  So that's not how merge works.

Instead, merge finds a snapshot that is *somewhere in the past*, back before `master` and `develop` *diverged*.  By comparing *that* snapshot with the one at the end of `master`, Git can see what has changed in `master`.  By comparing that *same* snapshot with the one at the end of `develop`, Git can see what has changed in `develop`.  And then, Git can *combine these two sets of changes*, so as to keep your changes, but add their changes as well.

This process is simple—well, relatively simple—algorithmically (though a lot of work in practice, which is why we have the *computer* do it).  In some cases it's *too* simple, and produces the wrong results.  Yours would appear to be one of those cases.

If you find the commit where the *bug itself is introduced* (some point in the past, perhaps the distant past) and make a branch where you fix that bug right after its introduction, you can then merge *this* branch into both `master` *and* `develop`.  The changes from this branch's merge base, with either `master` or `develop`, to this branch's tip will be *just the fix*.  The changes from this merge base to the tip of `master`, or the tip of `develop`, will be *everything else that happened*.  So merging *this* branch into both `master` and `develop` will typically produce the correct result, without introducing other, unwanted changes.  But that's often more difficult—sometimes *much* more difficult—than just making a hotfix branch for `master`.  So the choice is yours.

You could consider using `git cherry-pick` as a way to copy the hotfix to the `develop` branch.  Cherry-picking has its own hazards—for instance, if the hotfix proves to have its own bug(s), now you need to fix it twice—but it's another tool in the shop.  Git is a big shop with a lot of tools.  Pick the correct saw, file, hammer, plane, screwdriver, drill, and so on, and you'll get a lot of good things done.  Pick the wrong one and ... well...

---

<sup>1</sup>It could potentially print none at all, if the histories were unrelated, but in that case you would have seen an error about unrelated histories.